# add ngClass to all the divs clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-class

[image]

I'm trying to add 'active' class to all the divs (options in this case) that are clicked and remove the class on a second click.

The options count can vary as it's generated by ngFor.

HTML

```
<div [ngClass]="{'active': selectedOptions == i}" *ngFor="let opt of options; let i=index"
 (click)="answerSelectedMultiple(i)">
```

TS

```
answerSelectedMultiple(index){
    if(this.selectedOptions.indexOf(index) == -1){
        this.selectedOptions.push(index);
    }else{
        this.selectedOptions.splice(this.selectedOptions.indexOf(index), 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than applying a class/styling, do you need the selecttedOptions array for any other purpose/logic? If not, this could be easily capsulated in a directive

Comment: Can only one div be active at a time, or can multiple divs be active?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, no I don't need the selectedOptions

Comment: @ExplosionPills, multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capsulate this into a directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[activeOnClick]',
  // Optionally replace this both with properties marked 
  // with @HostBinding and @HostListener decorators
  host: {
    '[class.active]': 'clicked',
    '(click)': '_toggle()'
  }
})
export class ActiveOnClickDirective {
   @Input('activeOnClick')
   clicked = false;

   _toggle(){
      this.clicked= !this.clicked;
   }
}
```

After declaring the directive in a module, it could be used as follows:

```
<div activeOnClick *ngFor="let opt of options; let i=index">
```

In the case that you want to bind the flag value of the directive in the template:

```
<div [activeOnClick]="true" *ngFor="let opt of options; let i=index">
```

You could even expand this to dynamically apply different classes on the host element:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[classesOnClick]'
})
export class ClassesOnClickDirective { 
   @Input('classesOnClick')
   clicked = false;

   @Input()
   set class(value: string[]| string){
      let classes = Array.isArray(value) ? value : value.split(' ');
      classes = classes.filter(class => !!class);
      this._classes = classes;
   }
   private _classes: string [] = ['active'];

   constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2){}

   @HostListener('click')
   _toggle(){
      this.clicked = !this.clicked;
   }

   private _update(){
     this._classes.forEach(class => {
       if(this.clicked){
          this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, class);
       }else{
          this.renderer.removeClass(this.element.nativeElement, class);
       } 
     });
   }
}
```

Then use as follows:

```
<div [classesOnClick]="true" [classesOnClickClass]="['c1','c2']" *ngFor="let opt of options; let i=index">

<div [classesOnClick]="true" classesOnClickClass="c1 c2" *ngFor="let opt of options; let i=index">
```

Comment: Amazing! You are a legend!

Comment: Can I use this to add the active class if a key in options gives me an array of already selected answers?

Comment: Sure, as already shown in one of the examples, you can bind the starting value of the `clicked` flag to a value in the template

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: if you provide me a small plnkr/stackblitz repo I can help you out

Comment: Thank you so much! simply amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You can record active status on `opt`:

```
<div *ngFor="let opt of options" [ngClass]="{active: opt.active}"
  (click)="opt.active = !opt.active">
```